# Check for undefined or null in one call and assign False

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this function:

```
dosomething(): void {
this.service.check(this.person.name, this.person.name).subscribe(response => {
  this.isGreatPerson = response == null ? false :response;
});
}
```

`this.isGreatPerson` should get the `response` (true or false) and if the `response` is `undefined` or `null`, make `this.isGreatPerson` `false`. The solution should be in one line.

Thanks!

Comment: @Drenai They are for duplicates that cover this issue in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.isGreatPerson = !!response`

`!!` is the equivalent to converting any value into its boolean representation

If response is true or false it returns true or false, if it's null or undefined it returns false

Answer (score 1):

Since you literally just want the boolean equivalent of `response`, convert `response` to a boolean value:

```js
this.isGreatPerson = Boolean(response);
// or as Drenai wrote:
this.isGreatPerson = !!response;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just use braces, you can achieve a combined check for `null` and `undefined`.

```
doSomething(): void {
     this.service.check(this.person.name, this.person.name).subscribe(response => {
        this.isGreatPerson = (response) ? response : false;
     });
}
```

If `response` is nor `undefined` neither `null` it will be returned. Otherwise `false` is the answer.